# ActiveRecord: Nice way to get 2 calculations in the same query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an Rails model from which I want to query the `count` and the last `updated_at` timestamp.

Currently my code is this: `pluck('COUNT(*)', 'MAX(updated_at)')`, which is a bit ugly, since it returns an array of arrays and I keep thinking that theres a better way for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `pluck` takes attribute names as its argument.. right ? How you provide `count(*)` and the other one ?

Comment: could you tell me the logic, what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: will it work for you ? `find(:all, :select => "count(*),max('updated_at')", :group => 'updated_at')`

Comment: @ArupRakshit `pluck` takes attribute names or straight up SQL like I demonstrated. I'm trying to get the count of objects and the last updated timestamp, like I explained in my question.
Your example does not return the needed information and it takes a whole lot longer than my `pluck`

Answer (score 0):

You can query this as such:

```
model_stats = Model.select("count(*), max(updated_at) as last_update").first
```

The `model_stats` will be a `Model` with just the attributes `count` and `last_update`.

Comment: This seems to generate the right SQL I'd want, but it just returns an empty `Model`, with no new attributes

Comment: When I tested it on my side it seems to work - but it does not add the attributes to the attribute list on the Model so it won't `inspect` properly, but you should still be able to call them directly...

Comment: Well I wasn't able to call them. Did you accessors to the model or something?